# Chrome "Login Data" file can not be imported to another computer

Tags: windows, google-chrome, passwords

I read that all the Google Chrome passwords are saved in `C:\Users\Joel\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
in a file named `Login Data`.

So I tried to copy that file over from the original computer to another one with Chrome installed, put it there, but the passwords do not seem to go there....
Is there a way to send these passwords using this file? The target computer do not have internet, so I can't import them online...

Comment: [This answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/44498) might give some hints as to why it is not working.

Comment: what if the local account does not have a password?

Comment: The data is actually encrypted with a "master key" that is stored in your local profile and protected by your password ([see explaination](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/309408#3)), so a different machine protected by the same password would not have the same master key.